# Why do we use two different verb forms for sentences like “that person is broke” versus “that person is broken”?

Tags: meaning, past-participles, historical-change, inflectional-morphology, irregular-verbs

We usually use only a verb’s past participle when we
need to make an adjective out of it, not its past
tense—but not always.  Sometimes we even use both forms
but assign these two diﬀerent meanings!

For example, even though using *broke* as the past
participle for the verb *break* is now considered
obsolete, we still use that old form today for the
verb’s corresponding predicate adjective in sentences
like

1. Now I’m **broke**.

Using that obsolete form there in (1) means something
quite diﬀerent from what it mean here:

2. Now I’m **broken**.

Since both are adjectives, why do we sometimes use
an obsolete form for one sense but another form for
another possible sense? Why don’t we always use the
same more-standard form for both senses?

---

This leaves *break* with two **diﬀerent inﬂections**
available for potential use as adjectives, either the
past or the past participle, since historically *broke*
once alternated with *broken* as that verb’s past
participle but no longer does so.  Do other verbs ever
work like *break* works in this respect?  I’m
especially looking for now-obsolete past participles
still used today as adjectives that are spelled just
like the verb’s present or past forms instead of how
its past participle is spelled in perfect constructions
with *have*.

Comment: There’s also *If it ain’t broke, don’t fix it.”*

Comment: The past tense of *interleave* is *interleaved*, but that's not what you're looking for here.

Comment: **MODERATOR NOTE:** I have drastically refactored this question so that it can be an interesting and answerable question under our format, meaning one that’s no longer just a boring and off-topic list question.

Comment: @tchrist. you're welcome

Comment: @tchrist by editing the question so much, none of the answers are applicable at all. They're answering what I assume was "what are other examples of this phenomenon" instead of "why does this happen?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Other examples with differences in adjective usage/meaning/collocation for past particples:

(1) For *work* we have *worked* and *wrought* ("chiefly archaic"—OED)

**wrought** (adj.)

> Worked into shape by artistry or effort
> *carefully wrought essays*
>
> Elaborately embellished : ORNAMENTED
>
> Processed for use : MANUFACTURED
> *wrought silk*
>
> Beaten into shape by tools : HAMMERED —used of metals
> [*wrought iron*]
>
> Deeply stirred : EXCITED —often used with up
> *gets easily wrought up over nothing* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wrought)

> **Wrought derives from Middle English worken, the past participle of our very familiar verb work**, following similar verb patterns still
> in use today (caught, bought, taught). Nowadays, however, we simply
> use the standard –ed suffix for work: [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/wrought-past-tense-of-work)

**worked** (adj.)

> That has been subjected to some process of development, treatment, or
> manufacture
>
> *a newly worked field*
>
> *The watch is equipped with a new 22-karat rose gold open-worked oscillating weight.* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/worked)

> Prepared so as to demonstrate the steps required.
>
> *Place each error opposite its supposed number, as in the worked example.* [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/worked)

Similarly, from *overwork* we have *overworked* and *overwrought*.

**overwrought** (adj.)

> Exhausted by overwork; worked to excess. Also in extended use:
> over-excited; nervous; distraught.
>
> Excessively elaborate; over-laboured. Also (occasionally) figurative. OED

**overworked** (adj.)

> That has been overworked; that has been worked too hard or to excess.
> Also in extended use. OED

---

(2) We have **cleft, cloven** and **cleaved** for the verb *cleave* (with the meaning of *separate/divide*), all in use:

A *cleft* palate, a *cloven* hoof, and *cleaved* proteins.

In addition, we might give honorable mention to:

**clove** (adj.)

> = cloven adj. and n., formerly frequent, still occasionally in verse; rarely as adjective. OED

---

(3) **shrunk** and **shrunken** for to *shrink*

A *shrunken head* (or a *shrunken appearance*) and *preshrunk clothes*

(The OED notes that the attributive use of *shrunk* is "now somewhat rare.")

**shrunken** (adj.)

> Reduced in size : made less or smaller [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shrunken)
>
> *A netbook is a laptop with a shrunken screen, an undersize keyboard and a processor that's so slow, you'd have laughed at it in 2007.*

**preshrink, preshrank, preshrunk** (v.)

> To shrink (a fabric) before making into a garment so that it will not
> shrink much when washed [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/preshrink)

**preshrunk** (adj.)

> Of a fabric or garment: having undergone a shrinking process during
> manufacture to prevent further shrinking after washing or cleaning.
>
> *The youth shirts are blue-gray preshrunk 100% cotton.* OED

---

(4) Both past participles of *strike* (*struck* and *stricken*) are also adjectives; however, only *struck* is used to refer to a labor strike:

**stricken** (adj.)

> Struck with a blow.
>
> *Into fiery splinters leapt the lance, And out of stricken helmets sprang the fire*
>
> Of a person, community: Afflicted with disease or sickness;
> overwhelmed with trouble or sorrow, and the like. Of the face: Marked
> with or exhibiting great trouble.
>
> H. James—*Roderick's stricken state had driven him..higher and
> further than he knew.* OED

**struck** (adj.)

> Subjected to a blow or stroke. OED

> Closed by or subjected to a labor strike
>
> *a struck factory*
> *a struck employer* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/struck)

---

(5) For *beat* we have both *beat* and *beaten*:

*I was beat and slept most of the next day.*
*The store was definitely off the beaten path*.

**beat** (adj.)

> Being in a state of exhaustion : EXHAUSTED
>
> Sapped of resolution or morale [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beat)

**beaten** (adj.)

> Hammered into a desired shape
> *beaten gold*
>
> Much trodden and worn smooth also : FAMILIAR
> *a beaten path*
>
> Being in a state of exhaustion : EXHAUSTED [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beaten)

---

(6) For *melt* we have  the past participles **melted** and **molten** ("chiefly archaic"—OED).

I dipped the cookies in *melted* chocolate. Then I made a  *molten* chocolate cake.

**molten** (adj.)

> Fused or liquefied by heat : MELTED
> *molten lava*
>
> Having warmth or brilliance : GLOWING
> *the molten sunlight of warm skies* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/molten)

(We wouldn't say *the melted sunlight,* unless a photo was left on a radiator.)

Comment: I usually use *drink/drank/drunk/drunken* as my standard four-way example where there is a fourth form in common use as an adjective.

Comment: @tchrist You motivated me: I was able to squeak in*clove* :-)

Comment: You can find all kinds of them [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_irregular_verbs), but bear in mind that that list is far from complete. For example, it doesn't mention *foughten* or *boughten* or *writhen*, which have their own histories as participle forms used as adjectives. Pay especial attention to the paragraph beginning with *In some cases, there are two or more possibilities for a given form.*

Comment: Yes, I did check that page. For me the interest lies in cases where we  distingush(ed)  the different forms when used as adjectives.

Comment: The shift in meaning is definitely the interesting bit here. To that end, I’ve heavily edited the original to change it from being a boring and off-topic list question  to being something interesting and answerable according under our Q&A model. I realize that this just obsolesced all existing answers and places a burden on their authors to refactor their answers maybe leaving the old bits as examples supporting the thesis or disproving it. But the original was off-topic for good reason, and this was the only way I could think of to try to rescue it.

Answer (score 3):

**hung** is the simple past tense and past participle of *hang* for all uses *except* when referring to the method of execution; for that, both forms are **hanged**.

(Both words are also adjectives, but those uses are more complex, and this is a family show…)

Comment: A *hung* jury won't lead to a *hanged* man.

Answer (score 2):

#### 1) *'drunk'* vs *'drunken'*

***drunk*** is the past participle of *drink*.

However we also have [***drunken** (adj)*, which was once a past participle of *drink*, before the 17th century. Since then it has been mostly used as an adjective, and its function as a verb is now deemed archaic.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/usage-drank-vs-drunk)

#### 2) *'set'* vs *'setted'*

***set*** is the usual past participle of set. (Exams are set, jelly is set, someone's mind is set, etc.)

But one (or possibly two) dubious ways exist to 'achieve' the alternative past participle *setted*:

1. past tense of the business jargon [***level-set***](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/five-obfuscating-business-verbs) (*(verb) "to make sure that people [on the same team] all have the same information about the work"*) / *"get together to figure it out"* [CNN, 2014](https://money.cnn.com/2014/10/26/pf/corporate-jargon/)

   - *level-set* as business jargon (verb) has been unceremoniously [lifted from mathematics, where it's a respectable noun and means "the n-dimensional generalization of a contour"](https://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/Level+set). I first heard this business jargon blasphemy start appearing in the late 1990s/early 2000s.
   - don't blame me, blame MBA school
2. Wiktionary makes the (extremely dubious) claim that "[***setted***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/setted) is a simple past tense and past participle of set". Example meaning: *to divide students into different ability groups* (e.g. *"the students are setted by ability"*, I suppose).

   - Merriam-Webster and [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/jet-set?q=setted) say no. I couldn't find any reputable source saying yes.

Comment: For what it's worth, [a Google Books search](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=setted#ip=1) suggests that the most common meaning of "setted" is "grouped (or divided) into sets," and, in particular, "(of students) put into classes according to their level of ability."

Comment: Your "level-setted" is a form of the verb "level-set", which doesn't bear on the past participle of the verb" set". And the usage of "setted" you mention is from a verb "set" which is a different verb. That doesn't make a single verb with two past participles any more than cleave/cleaved and cleave/cloven do.

Answer (score 0):

**smote** is the simple past of **smite**, and **smitten** is the past participle. But [according to M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/smite-smote-smitten-smoted-smut-smit)

> There has been a great deal of overlap between these roles in the past 800 years or so, and again, both the past tense and the past participles have a good amount of variation (*smat*, *smet*, *smit*, *smot*, and *smyt*, are some of these variants, although, oddly enough, *smut* appears to not be one.

Answer (score 0):

sank, sunk and sunken, drowned and drownt

Drount/drownt was an old past participle. Shakespeare uses it in *All's Well, that Ends Well*